# npm ERR! code ENOENT errno -2 missing package.json?

Tags: javascript, package.json

I am quite new to JS. I am trying to install something from git with

`npm install git+https://github.com/celer-network/cBridge-typescript-client.git`

And I get

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/ich/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clonerawpRN/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/ich/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clonerawpRN/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ich/.npm/_logs/2022-01-11T11_09_15_020Z-debug-0.log
```

I am using PyCharm on a MacBook Pro.

Best,

Dominik

Comment: No, I have tried all the suggestions and I still get the err


``` rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force   ```

and 

```  rm package-lock.json && npm i   ```

and deleting package-lock.json manually

```
ich@Dominiks-MBP BridgeScript % npm install git+https://github.com/celer-network/cBridge-typescript-client.git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/ich/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneZFAP1v/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/ich/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneZFAP1v/package.json'
...
```

Comment: Hmm...my bad. I can confirm that it's a problem about whether this project or your installation command. Thus I deleted my comments.

Comment: It might be a problem with the repo. How about installing the package from the npm with the command `npm install grpc-web`? I think it's because they have packed their script to npm so you can just install and use it, but attempting to install from the source code doesn't really work.